# Preprocessing Yelp Dataset in R

Tags: r

Used code to change the directory :

```
setwd("~/R/capstone/yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset")
```

This is the error:

```
Error in setwd("~/R/yelp/yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset") : 
cannot change working directory
```

After typing code:

```
tip <- stream_in(file("yelp_academic_dataset_tip.json"))
checkin <- stream_in(file("yelp_academic_dataset_checkin.json"))
user <- stream_in(file("yelp_academic_dataset_user.json"))
review <- stream_in(file("yelp_academic_dataset_review.json"))
business <- stream_in(file("yelp_academic_dataset_business.json"))
```

Furthermore these are the errors:

```
opening file input connection.
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(con, "rb") :
cannot open file 'yelp_academic_dataset_business.json': No such file or directory
```

Comment: This is what I get when I try to load the dataset :                                  `Error: bad restore file     magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
    In addition: Warning message:
    file ‘yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset’ has magic number     'Datas'                                                                                                     Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated`

Comment: How to convert the dataset into R file?

Comment: Getting embedded nulls...

Comment: Not sure what package `stream_in` comes from. You will likely have to use a package like `rjson` or `RJONSIO` to read a json file. As far as setting the working directory, I think the error message should help. You have typed the directory wrong, or something.